# Azure vs Cloud Foundry

Tags: azure, cloud-foundry

I'm new to cloud foundry and would like to do a detailed comparison between Windows Azure and Cloud Foundry. I've searched around a lot but haven't been able to find anything useful. Is there a good post or some material which does a detailed feature wise comparison of the two?

Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 6):

You're not *exactly* comparing like for like here. Azure has IaaS type capability as well as PaaS, not only can you push applications to it but you can also deploy VM images too, including Linux.

However, as Cloud Foundry is open source the number of runtimes and frameworks if supports evolves quickly as VMWare openly encourage contributions from the OSS community. Correct me if I am wrong, but in a lot of cases, with Azure, you have to provide the runtime you wish to use where as Cloud Foundry supports them "natively", if that's the correct word?!

Right now, Cloud Foundry supports the following runtimes and frameworks;

#### Runtimes

java - 1.6.0_24
java7 - 1.7.0_04
node - 0.4.12
node06 - 0.6.8
node08 - 0.8.2
ruby18 - 1.8.7p357
ruby19 - 1.9.2p180

#### Frameworks

grails
java_web
lift
node
play
rack
rails3
sinatra
spring
standalone

They also provide all the major storage services too, including MySQL, Postgres, RabbitMQ and Redis.

The actual open source project supports a whole lot more too!

Comment: Thanks Dan! I'll go through this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Azure. But, I've used Cloudfoundry. Its great for Java deployments. I use VMC from Ruby gem for deployment and its so 3 - 4 step easy way to push your WAR to cloudfoundry server. They also provide neat documentation for configuration and setup. Oh and adding services (like Mongo DB, MySql) are also very simple. Though,sometimes, debugging server related issues are annoying with it. But, overall, its good for me :)

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/deploying-apps.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers, really appreciate it. I've actually used Windows Azure a lot, I wanted to do a feature wise comparison on things like security, storage, scaling, caching, messaging, identity management, geo-availability and so on.

Comment: Now that Cloud Foundry PaaS is released on Azure does anyone have any updated comment on this?

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, I don't know much about Cloud Foundry but I'm using Windows Azure for a couple of client projects and I have to say that I'm now very impressed with the development environment. I'm using the Websites Preview feature with continuous Git deployment via BitBucket. Setting this up is a breeze and allows me to push my changes to BitBucket and have Windows Azure deploy them automatically for me. There's currently no ability to run unit tests as part of the deployment cycle as per other cloud platforms (e.g. AppHarbor) but the feature set for getting up and running with a .NET application and SQL Azure database is now pretty slick. Here's a couple of links:

[Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Web Site and SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/)

[Continuous Deployment with Windows Azure Websites and Bitbucket](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/continuous-deployment-with-windows-azure-websites-and-bitbucket/)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, really appreciate it. I've actually used Windows Azure a lot, I wanted to do a feature wise comparison on things like security, storage, scaling, caching, messaging, identity management, geo-availability and so on.